# Delphi SearchText Issue

Tags: delphi

For some reason, using

```
   SearchText := 'Program Files';
   ReplaceText := 'Program Files (x86)';
   SearchAndReplace(SearchText, ReplaceText);
```

Would do absolutely nothing, it just won't change text, works fine when using any other text.

Is this some sort of "Reserve" word? Or ( ) is what makes it do not work?

```
procedure Tfc_Great.SearchAndReplace
           (InSearch, InReplace: string) ;
var X, ToEnd : integer;
    oldCursor : TCursor;
begin
   oldCursor := Screen.Cursor;
   Screen.Cursor := crHourglass;
   with RichEdit1 do
   begin
     X := 0;
     ToEnd := length(Text) ;
     X := FindText(inSearch, X, ToEnd, []) ;
     while X <> -1 do
     begin
       SetFocus;
       SelStart := X;
       SelLength := length(inSearch) ;
       SelText := InReplace;
       X := FindText(inSearch,
                     X + length(InReplace),
                     ToEnd, []) ;
     end;
   end;
   Screen.Cursor := oldCursor;
end;
```

Comment: which version of Delphi you are using?

Comment: What's the wider context?  I've never heard of a SearchAndReplace function and I can't find any helpfile entries on it.  Is this part of a component?  I usually use StringReplace for search-and-replace operations.

Comment: I don't get it. Which string do you intend to modify?

Comment: I am using

RichEdit.Lines.LoadFromFile(mfp, TEncoding.ASCII);

Edited original post.

Comment: Just a guess but the replace text might be truncated when inserted.  The selected region is shorter than the new string.
SelLength := length(inSearch);  // 13 chars
SelText := InReplace;           // 19 chars

Comment: @larryb82: setting SelText will replace the selected text with your text, no matter the length.

Comment: @Tom: I compiled your code and it works fine. Program Files is getting replaced with Program Files (x86). I'm on Delphi 7. Is the RichEdit1 from your SearchAndReplace procedure the same one you are looking at? There is only one catch: you're setting ToEnd at the start, but while replacing, the length of your Text changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to assign the output ;)

```
SearchText := 'Program Files';
ReplaceText := 'Program Files (x86)';
ResultText := SearchAndReplace(Text, SearchText, ReplaceText);
```

with

```
function SearchAndReplace
   (sSrc, sLookFor, sReplaceWith : string) : string;
var
   nPos, nLenLookFor : integer;
begin
   nPos := Pos(sLookFor, sSrc) ;
   nLenLookFor := Length(sLookFor) ;
   while (nPos > 0) do begin
     Delete(sSrc, nPos, nLenLookFor) ;
     Insert(sReplaceWith, sSrc, nPos) ;
     nPos := Pos(sLookFor, sSrc) ;
   end;
   Result := sSrc;
end;
```

Comment: I am using

RichEdit.Lines.SaveToFile(mfp, TEncoding.ASCII);

Comment: RichEdit.Lines.LoadFromFile(mfp, TEncoding.ASCII);

Comment: What's in RichEdit? The text you want to replace? What's in mfp?